# Finding a base for matrix representation of a linear map

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I was given the following problem:

Let $T: \Bbb F^2 \to \Bbb F^2$ be  linear map such that $T^2=0$. Prove that either $T=0$ or there is a base $B \subset \Bbb F^2$ such that 
$[T]^B_{B}=\begin{pmatrix}
        0 & 0  \\
        1 & 0  \\
        \end{pmatrix}$

It is easy to see that if we multiply $[T]^B_{B}$ by itself we get a matrix of zeros. Am I missing something here? I would like to get some guidance in solving \ formalizing. Thanks

Comment: What you're missing is that you are supposed to prove that there is a basis for which $T$ has the above matrix. What you are doing is using the fact that you need to prove.

Comment: Any hints then? pretty stuck

Comment: O.K. Assume $T\neq 0$. Then there must be some $v\neq 0$ such that $u=Tv\neq 0$. Prove that $u,v$ are linearly independent and find out what is the matrix of $T$ with respect to the basis $\{u,v\}$.